# Литература по теме "Современные англоязычные словари мифологем."

Tags: литература, недопустимая-метка

Может обращаюсь не по адресу, но очень рассчитываю на помощь. 
Требуется материал для курсовой работы по теме "Современные англоязычные словари мифологем."

Есть материал по англоязычным мифологегам, современным мифологемам, их использовании и пр., а вот именно по современным англоязычным словарям мифологем ничего не могу найти. Может быть кто-нибудь знает ресурсы или книги, материал которых можно использовать в написании работы? Заранее огромная благодарность!

Comment: Может, стоит поискать мифологические словари?  Такие есть, и общие, и по народам. А в них есть ссылки на другие источники.

Comment: Спасибо все огромное за участие. Всё уточню у препода, учту обязательно ваши советы и подсказки!

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:1.научная библиотека, там есть электронный поиск материалов, брать сами словари и анализировать

2.Посмотреть библиографию диссертаций по англоязычным мифологемам.

3.Может, что-то отсюда выудите. http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192801463.001.0001/acref-9780192801463?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=title&source=%2F10.1093%2Facref%2F9780192801463.001.0001%2Facref-9780192801463

4.Обратиться к преподавателю. Если дал такую тему, видимо, есть и материал. Пусть даст список литературы.

Comment: 1.В России есть мифологические словари, а про англоязычные не знаю.Мне не встретилось ни разу, но нужно смотреть на соответствующих сайтах, я английский не изучала. Вот по моей ссылке, по-моему, как раз словарь, составленный учёными Оксфордского университета (А может, просто книга, не знаю, посмотрите)В любом случае, названия будут звучать не как Словарь мифологем. 2.Словарь мифологем не обязательно словарь фразеологизмов, и в словаре фразеологизмов не обязательно будут мифологемы, но чаще они там есть. Вы можете сказать, что мифологемы представлены и в таких-то словарях фразеологизмов...

Comment: Ещё совет: зайдите на "Ответы" (на мейле.ру), там есть Сергей Петров и Александра,напишите им в "мир"или на почту, я думаю, ответят, да и вообще вопрос можно задать, зарегистрировавшись, ответов будет много (в Лингвистике). Может, кто-то и поможет, там сильные "англичане".

Answer (score 0):

Мне вообще кажется сперва надо уточнить у преподавателя, что он понимает под словом "мифологемы". Всё-таки основное значение слова "мифолгема" - это  некая первичная сюжетная схема, своеобразная кросскультурная идея, встречающаяся в фольклоре разных народов. Как возможен сам по себе "словарь сюжетных схем", лично я представляю слабо.

Сами по себе работы по анализу мифологем, конечно существуют, но тут легко запутаться. Дело в том, что существуют несколько школ с различным взглядами на мифологемы и далеко не все учёные вообще используют данный термин.

Так, основатель аналитической психологии К.-Г. Юнг ввел в науку понятие архетип и различал в качестве важнейших мифологических архетипов или архетипических мифологем архетипы “матери”, “тени”, “анимуса”, “анимы”, “мудрого старика” (“мудрой старухи”). Они выражают ступени того, что Юнг называет процессом индивидуации, т. е. постепенного выделения индивидуального сознания из коллективно-бессознательного в человеческой личности вплоть до их окончательной гармонизации в конце жизни. Архетипы описывают бессознательные душевные события в образах внешнего мира, т. е. истоки мифологических сюжетов сводятся к внутренней жизни души. Согласно ритуализму (основатель – Д. Д. Фрэзер), основа мифов и мифологических сюжетов – это ритуалы, в частности, исследованная в “Золотой ветви” Фрэзера мифологема  периодически умерщвляемого и замещаемого царя-колдуна, магически ответственного за урожай и за семейное благополучие. Ритуально-мифологическая школа (Н. Фрай, М. Бодкин) сводит истоки сюжетов к обрядам или природным циклам. Структурализм (характерный представитель – Леви-Стросс) делает акцент на цельности мифического сюжета, который имеет некий общий смысл, неразложимый на отдельные звенья. Основоположник cтруктурной фольклористики В. Я. Пропп, опираясь на миф, создал модель метасюжета волшебной сказки в виде линейной последовательности функций действующих лиц; в качестве общей основы структуры волшебной сказки им рассматривается обряд инициации. Е. М. Мелетинскому принадлежит описание классических форм мифа (архаические мифы творения, героические мифы и т. п.), перехода от мифа к эпосу и волшебной сказке, анализ видов мифологических образов в литературе Возрождения, современном романе и т. п.; при этом он вводит и использует понятие мифологемы.

В общем, при такой теме надо по идее искать, что-то вроде энциклопедий символов, архетипических сюжетов и т.п. Хотя возможно имеются в виду и просто словари мифологических персонажей. В первом случае странно смотрится слово "словарь", во втором "мифологем", поэтому ещё раз посоветую обратится к преподавателю за разъяснением темы.

Comment: В филологических вузах Мифологема- универсальные сюжеты и образы мифов. Например, мифологема воды - все мифы(сюжеты), связанные с водой.Мать-земля - все сюжеты, связанные с этим образом. Собственно, наши мифологические словари построены тоже по такому типу: образ - и все мифические истории, с ним связанные.Архетип - та же мифологема, только прижившаяся на русской почве (или на англоязычной - в Великобритании, Америке и т.д.).Вероятно, такие словари и имеются в виду.

Comment: @Людмила, я об этом тоже писал. Но те словари мифологии, которые мне попадались, описывали скорее мифических персонажей, чем мифологемы. С мифологемного подхода, нужно смотреть "гроза", а словарь мифологии будет рассказывать о Зевсе, Перуне, Юпитере, Торе и прочих. Поэтому я и написал, что тут скорее подходят энциклопедии символов, так как там эти символы трактуют именно мифологемным образом, правда, как правило, без указания конкретных мифов, где это отражено.

Архетип - та же мифологема, только не в филологии, а в психологии. В любом случае, надо понять о чём курсовая не "вероятно", а точно